# PyArrow ParquetWriter: Is there a way to limit the size of the output file (splitting)?

Tags: pyarrow

Use the [finer grained reading and writing example for the pyarrow documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html#finer-grained-reading-and-writing)

```
writer = pq.ParquetWriter('example2.parquet', table.schema)

for i in range(300000):
  writer.write_table(table)
  # Is it possible to know how many bytes have been written out to the files after compression?

writer.close()
```

I want to limit the output file size to 200-300MB, If tried to get the `writer.file_handle.size()` but that raises a `*** OSError: only valid on readable files`. Is there a good way to limit the size the output file?

Comment: There is an open ticket for doing this through the datasets API: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-10439

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any way to limit the outfile file size directly but it's possible  to control it indirectly by limiting the number of bytes fed to the `ParquetWriter`.

```py
bytes_written = 0
index = 0
writer = pq.ParquetWriter(f'output_{index:03}.parquet', table.schema)

for i in range(300000):
  writer.write_table(table)
  bytes_written = bytes_written + table.nbytes
  if bytes_written >= 500000000: # 500MB, start a new file
    writer.close()
    index = index + 1
    writer = pq.ParquetWriter(f'output_{index:03}.parquet', table.schema)
    bytes_written = 0

writer.close()
```

In my case each 500MB of uncompressed table data gives a parquet file around 45MB. The files will be named `test_000.parquet`, `test_001.parquet`, etc.